# ubuntu 16.04 some websites are not connected : Solved

Tags: networking, dns

I have a new ubuntu 16.04 machine, I have setup the ip adderss, default router and DNS server.
I can browse the network, like google, browse the websites from google search, and use askubuntu.com (I'm using this ubuntu machine now).
But when I try to connect some networks, like chosun.com (a Korean newspaper company), it would not connect. All other computers I use can connect to that site.
Also, when I try to do apt-get update, I see there are some connection failure report, but when I do ping for the failed IP addresses, they ping back ok.
I looked for the solution on the web, but couldn't find one that suites me.
What can be the problem?

**ADD (After it was Solved):**

I changed my IP address to one in another segment (from 129.254.32.X to 129.254.31.X) then all worked fine! I can do apt-get update, apt-get install .. and can read chosun.com fast. So it seem it was our network problem.
I leave this question here so that someone can get help in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Try to see if you can ping chosun.com. I see they use the following IP, 112.175.104.100. You can try to enter that into your browser. If the site loads with the numerical IP but not he domain name, you may have a DNS issue.

Look in `/etc/resolv.conf` for your DNS servers. If you receive your network information via DHCP this may be set automatically. If you have another working computer, which can connect to site(s) with their domain name(s)s, then see what the DNS server settings are on the working computer, and make sure the two computer's settings match.

You can also try, temporarily, to use Google's DNS servers: `8.8.8.8`, and `8.8.4.4`, and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Hi, I just solved it by changing my IP address to one in different segment . (from 129.254.32.X to 129.254.31.X), so it was a network problem. I tried several DNS servers before. Thanks.!

Answer (score 0):

It was our network problem. I changed my IP address (and router accordingly) and all problems went away! See my updated question.